# How to set multiple metrics for setDailyMetric method while sending request to Business Profile Performance API?

Tags: java, google-my-business-api, google-my-business, google-business-profile-api

Following this link [getDailyMetricsTimeSeries](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest/v1/locations/getDailyMetricsTimeSeries#DailyMetric), I wanna have all the metrics in one request, since I have many locations for every client, it does not seem to be professional if I send one separate request for every single metric.

before in [Google My business V4.9](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/Metric) we could use "ALL" to request all available metrics. Unfortunately, this is not working with the new API. Can I get ALL the metrics in ONE single request from Google Business Profile Performance API?

Here is my code in JAVA:
supposing that the variable *business_profile_performance* is the initialiser global parameters via its Builder and also takes care of authentication.

```
try {

                BusinessProfilePerformance.Locations.GetDailyMetricsTimeSeries metricReport =
                        business_profile_perfomance.locations().
                        getDailyMetricsTimeSeries("My locationID" ).
                        setDailyMetric(dailyMetric).
                        setDailyRangeStartDateYear(Integer.valueOf("the desired start Year")).
                        setDailyRangeStartDateMonth(Integer.valueOf(" the desired start Month" )).
                        setDailyRangeStartDateDay(Integer.valueOf(" the desired start Day ")).

                        setDailyRangeEndDateYear(Integer.valueOf("the desired End Year" )).
                        setDailyRangeEndDateMonth(Integer.valueOf(" the desired End Month")).
                        setDailyRangeEndDateDay(Integer.valueOf("the desired End Day"));

                GetDailyMetricsTimeSeriesResponse response = metricReport.execute();
                if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(dailyMetric + " Response == " + response);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
```

I used a list for my *dailyMetric* variable, and using a for loop it takes turn as photo below:

[image]

Comment: I have the same question, and additionally, the old `reportInsights` API allows getting insights from up to 10 locations, while `getDailyMetricsTimeSeries` seems to take only one location at a time. It is very very unfortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of March 16th, 2023, Google added a new method [locations.fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest/v1/locations/fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries#MultiDailyMetricTimeSeries) that serves the same function as "ALL" in the old 4.9 API.

Answer (score 1):

If setting `dailyMetric` to `"CALL_CLICKS"` works and setting it to `"CALL_CLICKS,WEBSITE_CLICKS"` does not work, it would seem that the new API does not support that use case anymore.

Comment: yes, it is exactly like what you said. it works, unfortunately, with only a single `dailyMetric` during each request.